# Can onChange's event read only the inner tag's value?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, dropdown, html-select, menuitem

I have a `Select` dropdown that listed some `MenuItems`, but now I want to add a `ListSubheader`. I am having issue grabbing the `event.target.value` from my `MenuItem` because I have to wrap them in a `div` tag, and the event is only checking the outer `div` tag for values.

Old `menuItems` and select dropdown:

```js
menuItems = [
{name: 'option A', value: 'optionA'}, 
{name: 'option B', value: 'optionB'},
{name: 'option C', value: 'optionC'}
]
```

```js
<Select onChange={(event) => {console.log(event.target.value}}>
  menuItems.map((menuItem) => {
    return {
      <MenuItem value={menuItem.value}> 
        {menuItem.name}
      </MenuItem>
    }
  })
</Select>
```

This works fine.

But in order to add a `ListSubheader`, I had to created `newMenuItem`s that looks something like this

```js
newMenuItems = [
  {subheader: 'subheader 1', items: [
    {name: 'option A', value: 'optionA'}
  ]},
  {subheader: 'subheader 2', items: [
    {name: 'option B', value: 'optionB'},
    {name: 'option C', value: 'optionC'}
  ]}
]
```

and my new select dropdown

```js
<Select onChange={(event) => {console.log(event.target.value}}>
  newMenuItems.map((ele) => {
    return {
      <div>
        <ListSubheader>{ele.subheader}</ListSubheader>
        
        {ele.items.map((menuItem) => {
          return (
            <MenuItem value={menuItem.value}> 
              {menuItem.name}
            </MenuItem>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    }
  })
</Select>
```

As you can see, in my new select dropdown, I had to wrap the `ListSubheader` and `MenuItem` in a `div` tag, and I can't use empty tag because `Select` tag does not like Fragments.

I am hoping to be able to select my options in the same way as before, is there a way for event to skip the outer tag and simply look for the value in the `MenuItem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the issue is that you are returning `div`s as options however the mui `Select` component expect `ListSubheader`s and `MenuItem`s as children ([Grouping](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/#grouping)).
with your code above you can't even select any option

one solution is to create a function that returns an array based on a given array:

```js
const createOptions = (array) => {
  let options = [];
  array.forEach((element) => {
    options.push(<ListSubheader>{element.subheader}</ListSubheader>);
    element.items.forEach((item) => {
      options.push(<MenuItem value={item.value}>{item.name}</MenuItem>);
    });
  });
  return options;
}
```

Now you can use it to return options to the `Select` component :

```js
<Select
  onChange={(event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }}
>
  {createOptions(newMenuItems).map((element) => element)}
</Select>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is so straightforward that i am a bit mad i didn't think of it myself.